# how to get the xml id used in first class to use in second class in android

Tags: android

I'm getting the android xml id in first Activity

(e.g)

```
setContentView(R.layout.sample);
button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b_one);
button2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b_two);
```

Now the problem is how can i use the same button in second Activity without using          `findViewById()`.

(i.e) I don't want to access xml in second Activity rather than that i have to   access those button ID from the first Activity itself.

I'm trying this to create a common header.

Please help me.

Comment: On android etch activity has its own views. for a comment header just make an abstract class witch extends Activity and include the header layout.

Comment: use include or merge in your xml

Answer (score 0):

You can't, because your buttons from two different activities will **not** share the same instance.

What you can do instead, if you want to have some common code for your header is to delegate this code in a static method of a third class. For example :

```
public class MyHeader {

    private Button button1,button2;

    public MyHeader(Activity source) {
       this.button1 = (Button)source.findViewById(R.id.b_one);
       this.button2 = (Button)source.findViewById(R.id.b_two); 
       // ...
       }

    public Button getHeaderButtonOne() { return button1; }
    // And so on...
    }
```

and in your activities, keep an instance of this class (initialized with :

```
  private MyHeader header;

  // ... in onCreate() method
  header = new MyHeader(this);
```

Comment: In the same way how can I set the click event for button1 in MyHeader class and  use that click event in another class

Comment: Why would you do that ? If there's some common code, then write it on your MyHeader class. If it's specific, then let the activities set a OnClickListener for the button. If you insist, you can define some `MyHeader.setButton1ClickListener(OnClickListener)` methods to delegate the `setOnClickListener` method call. Think *delegation* !